# how to get scala string split to match python

Tags: python, scala, split, apache-spark

I am using spark-shell and pyspark to do word count on one article. scala flatmap on line.split(" ") and python split() get different word counts (scala has more). I tried split(" +") and split("\W+") in the scala code, but can not get the count to come down to the same as the python one.

Anyone knows what pattern would match python exactly?

Comment: can you paste your code here?

Answer (score 0):

Python's [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) has some special behaviour for default separator:

> runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace. Consequently, splitting an empty string or a string consisting of just whitespace with a `None` separator returns `[]`.
>
> For example, `' 1  2   3  '.split()` returns `['1', '2', '3']`

The easiest way to fully match this in Scala is probably like this:

```
scala> """\S+""".r.findAllIn(" 1  2   3  ").toList
res0: List[String] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> """\S+""".r.findAllIn("   ").toList
res1: List[String] = List()

scala> """\S+""".r.findAllIn("").toList
res2: List[String] = List()
```

Another way is to `trim()` the string beforehand:

```
scala> " 1  2   3  ".trim().split("""\s+""")
res3: Array[String] = Array(1, 2, 3)
```

But that doesn't have the same behaviour as Python for empty strings:

```
scala> "".trim().split("""\s+""")
res4: Array[String] = Array("")
```

In Scala `split()` of an empty string returns an array with *one* element, but in Python the result is a list with *zero* elements.